# How to display limited characters in smarty?

Tags: smarty

I am receiving a paragraph content in smarty. While displaying i need to display only 25 characters how to limit characters in smarty.

```
<p>{$myresult}</p>
```

Now i am simply displaying. How to display only 25 characters from smarty content

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Usage of Truncate in smarty...**

**CODES**

```
{$articleTitle}
{$articleTitle|truncate}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:""}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:"---"}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:"":true}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:"...":true}
{$articleTitle|truncate:30:'..':true:true}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Two Sisters Reunite after Eighteen Years at Checkout Counter.
Two Sisters Reunite after Eighteen Years at Checkout Counter.
Two Sisters Reunite after...
Two Sisters Reunite after
Two Sisters Reunite after---
Two Sisters Reunite after Eigh
Two Sisters Reunite after E...
Two Sisters Re..ckout Counter.
```

Comment: Documentation on the various flags at: https://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.truncate.tpl

Answer (score 0):

If the substring filter is installed (I think its installed default):

```
{$myresult|substring:1:25}
```

If not, check out this site:

http://smarty.incutio.com/?page=substring